# How do I generate a pre-signed URL in Google Cloud Function that links to a specific bucket GCS?

Tags: python, google-cloud-functions, pre-signed-url, signed-url

How do I add the private key file generated with service account to the cloud function to authenticate ?

The following code returns an auth credential error, it says I need a private key to sign credentials. How do I create this and pass in the cloud function?

```
import datetime

from google.cloud import storage


def generate_download_signed_url_v4(bucket_name, blob_name):
    """Generates a v4 signed URL for downloading a blob.

    Note that this method requires a service account key file. You can not use
    this if you are using Application Default Credentials from Google Compute
    Engine or from the Google Cloud SDK.
    """
    # bucket_name = 'your-bucket-name'
    # blob_name = 'your-object-name'

    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(blob_name)

    url = blob.generate_signed_url(
        version="v4",
        # This URL is valid for 15 minutes
        expiration=datetime.timedelta(minutes=15),
        # Allow GET requests using this URL.
        method="GET",
    )

    print("Generated GET signed URL:")
    print(url)
    print("You can use this URL with any user agent, for example:")
    print("curl '{}'".format(url))
    return url
```

Comment: I provided [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64245028/11372593) today. It also works on CLoud Function and you don't need Service Account Key File (that is safer). Does it enough for you?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere still getting the same auth issue, "you need a private key to sign credentials"....not sure what to do

Comment: What's are your dependencies' version? Can you share them?

Comment: did you find an answer for this?

Answer (score 0):

I can help you to find information on how to create a signed url in GCF using Python. You need to use [Cloud Storage Python Client libraries](https://googleapis.dev/python/storage/latest/client.html), as explained in this [example](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/writing/http#writing_http_signed-python) on official GCP documentation. Also this [example](https://medium.com/@kennethjiang/google-cloud-storage-signed-url-in-python-3d12b4ae3330) on Medium can help you.

Comment: Thanks @Jaroslav --- main issue, is it's not sure where to add the private key file so the service account the cloud function it's linked to can be authenticated?

Comment: Applications use service accounts to make authorized API calls, authorized as either the service account itself. Do you need to use private key for it?