# Google Cloud Storage access via service account

Tags: python, django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I've been repetitively hitting my head against the proverbial brick wall of GCP's Storage API.

I'm trying to apply the django-storages module to connect with a GCP bucket for my static files and anything else I want to use it for in the future.

According to the django-storages documentation (https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html#usage), if you are running in the GCP virtual environment, you set your service account to have Storage permissions via the IAM interface and everything should work like tickety-boo.

So, my GCP cloud build runner builds the docker images then runs `python manage.py migrate` and `python manage.py collectstatic` before deploying my docker image to CloudRun. The build runner uses a service account called `XXXX@cloudbuild.gserviceaccount.com`, so going into IAM, I add the “Cloud storage – Storage admin” role, and just to be sure, I also add the “Cloud storage – Storage object admin” role.

Now I trigger a re-run of my cloudbuild and ... at the migrate stage I receive the error:

```
...
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 843, in exec_module
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/src/lang/urls.py", line 20, in <module>
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     re_path('favicon.ico$', RedirectView.as_view(url=staticfiles_storage.url('images/apple_touch_icon.png'), permanent=False)),
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/storages/backends/gcloud.py", line 290, in url
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     return blob.generate_signed_url(
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/blob.py", line 620, in generate_signed_url
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     return helper(
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_signing.py", line 550, in generate_signed_url_v4
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     ensure_signed_credentials(credentials)
Step #2 - "apply migrations":   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/google/cloud/storage/_signing.py", line 52, in ensure_signed_credentials
Step #2 - "apply migrations":     raise AttributeError(
Step #2 - "apply migrations": AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.
Finished Step #2 - "apply migrations"
```

Huh. I can't seem to authenticate via service worker.

Using code from the google example tutorial on django, I have the following line in my settings.py:

```
credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()
```

But I don't do anything with the credentials variable returned. It seems to me the documentation is a little sparse online as to how to access buckets via service accounts. Any insights?

Comment: I'm very familiar with GCP and Google's other Python SDKs but I'm unfamiliar with Django and this SDK. However, I found [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/samples/storage-generate-signed-url-v4) sample and the comment states that, when generating a Signed URL (which your library referenes), you can't use a Compute Engine Service Account (which you are) and Application Default Credentials (which you are). I don't actually understand why this is so but the solution would be to generate a Service Account and key specifically for this code.

Comment: The reason for the spurious `credentials, project_id = google.auth.default()` is that, the library defaults to the same underlying functionality for you (using ADCs) and so this step is redundant. Because it appears you'll need to use an explicit Service Account (key), you'll need the equivalent [step](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html#gs-creds)

Comment: With the Go [sample](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signing-urls-with-helpers#storage-signed-url-object-go), the comment is slightly more precise: "This authentication must include a private key or have `iam.serviceAccounts.signBlob` permissions".

Comment: Aha @john-hanley addresses this issue in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70934615/609290)

Comment: Thanks @DazWilkin , your thoughts got me hunting in a new direction and I've figured it out. Kudos to you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found a user with a similar issue: https://pnote.eu/notes/django-app-engine-user-uploaded-files/

Appears that the problem occurs for buckets that have a bucket access policy that is `Uniform` instead of `fine-grained`. The author of the above article lodged an issue with django-storage and a fix was eventually merged in. There is now a "Note" box in the documentation that I missed that states:

> GS_DEFAULT_ACL: When using this setting, make sure you have fine-grained access control enabled on your bucket, as opposed to Uniform access control, or else, file uploads will return with HTTP 400. If you already have a bucket with Uniform access control set to public read, please keep GS_DEFAULT_ACL to None and set GS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH to False.

So in short, the solution is to add to your settings.py file:

```
GS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```