# Creating credentials file on server via Dockerfile & Google cloud secret manager

Tags: django, docker, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google cloud build for CI/CD for my django app, and one requirement I have is to set my `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` so I can perform authenticated actions in my Docker build. For example, I need to run `RUN python manage.py collectstatic --noinput` which requires access to my Google cloud storage buckets.

I've generated the credentials and it works well when simply including it in my (currently private) repo as a .json file, so it gets pulled into my Docker container with the `COPY . .` command and setting the env variable with `ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json`. Ultimately, I want to grab the credential value from secret manager and create the credentials file during the build stage, so I can completely remove the credentials from the repo. I tried doing this with editing `cloudbuild.yaml` (referencing [this doc](https://cloud.google.com/build/docs/securing-builds/use-secrets)) with various implementations of the `availableSecrets` config, `$$SECRET` syntax, and `build-args` in the docker build command and trying to access in Dockerfile with

```
ARG GOOGLE_BUILD_CREDS
RUN echo "$GOOGLE_BUILD_CREDS" >> credentials.json
ENV GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS=credentials.json
```

with no success.

If someone could advise me how to implement this in my cloudbuild.yaml and Dockerfile if its possible, or if there's another better solution altogether, would be much appreciated.

This is the relevant part of my `cloudbuild.yaml`

```
steps:
  - name: gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker
    args:
      - build
      - '--no-cache'
      - '-t'
      - '$_GCR_HOSTNAME/$PROJECT_ID/$REPO_NAME/$_SERVICE_NAME:$COMMIT_SHA'
      - .
      - '-f'
      - Dockerfile
    id: Build
availableSecrets:
  secretManager:
  - versionName: projects/PROJECT_ID/secrets/CREDENTIALS/versions/latest
    env: 'CREDENTIALS'
```

Comment: Will your container run on Google Cloud or somewhere else?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere it's a Google Cloud Run service

Answer (score 2):

If your container will run on Cloud Run, it's super easy: Remove the service account key file (and roughly, in most use cases, you never ever need it).

Keep in mind that a service account key file is a secret with a private key. And if you put it in your container, you simply store it in plain text. So bad for a secret!! (with [dive](https://github.com/wagoodman/dive), you can explore your container content, and steal the secret if you have access to the container directly)

But, I'm sure you know that because you want to store the secret in a secret manager. Now a question? How do you access a secret manager? Do you need a service account key file to be authenticated to access it?

In fact not.

---

The solution is to use [ADC (Application default credentials)](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication). With the client libraries, use the get default credential method to let the library determine automatically the platform and the credential to use

On Cloud Run (as any other Google Cloud services), you have a [metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/metadata/overview) that allows client libraries to get credentials information from the [runtime service account](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/configuring/service-accounts).

On your local environment, you have 2 options:

- Use your own credential. For that run the command `gcloud auth application-default login`. It's your own credential and permissions, not exactly the same as the Cloud Run runtime environment
- Impersonate the Cloud Run runtime service account and act as itself to run your container/code locally. For that run the command `gcloud auth application-default login --impersonate-service-account=<service account email>`, Be sure to have the role service account token creator on the service account.

And then, run your app locally, and let the ADC use the credentials

Comment: The library which runs this command [django-storages](https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/gcloud.html) already attempts to grab the default credentials, but fails with this error: `google.auth.exceptions.DefaultCredentialsError: Could not automatically determine credentials. Please set GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS or explicitly create credentials and re-run the application.` which is why I initially switched the json file route

Answer (score 1):

I think I've worked out a fix. To solve the error I mentioned in my reply to @guillaume-blaquiere, I updated my build args in `cloudbuild.yaml` to include `--network=cloudbuild`, allowing me access to the correct service account credentials (credit to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70143131/application-default-credentials-in-google-cloud-build)).
The next issue I faced is with the django-storages library, returning this exception

```
AttributeError: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token. see https://googleapis.dev/python/google-api-core/latest/auth.html#setting-up-a-service-account for more details.
```

I then came across [this suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223722/google-cloud-storage-access-via-service-account) to add the setting [GS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71223722/google-cloud-storage-access-via-service-account) to my django config and this seems to do the trick. My only conern is the documentation here does not go into too much detail on impacts or risks of disabling this (the bucket is public-read as it recommends). It seems to be working as intended however. So I will go with this configuration unless a better solution is put forward.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of the library? Because YES, initially a service account key file was required to perform signedURL. But, I submitted this [pull request](https://github.com/googleapis/python-storage/pull/356), to be able to sign directly with the service account credential API and avoid the service account key files. If you are up to date, you should open an issue in the Django project, or consider not using that library.

Comment: Upgraded for good measure but judging by the date of your PR, seems like that should not be the issue in my case. Found an open issue with exactly [this issue](https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages/issues/941) for the `django-storages` library. And seems the workaround provided by danfairs works for other commenters. But given that my bucket is public read (only deletes/uploads need to be restricted), I'm not sure I even need to do this, as the settings in my answer seem to match the docs' recommendations. Are there any implications of forcing them not to be signed instead?