How to get access to service account private key for PreSigned URLS?
Keep getting "An error occurred: you need a private key to sign credentials.the credentials you are currently using <class 'google.auth.compute_engine.credentials.Credentials'> just contains a token"
I'm Trying to get Presigned URL so that it can be downloaded by app(for user profile)
It works fine in my local since I have key path to the service account json key.
In cloud run I've tried secret manager but it didn't work, since instead of file it shows the value of the key itself.
bucket_name = os.environ.get("BUCKET_NAME")
service_account = os.environ.get("SERVICE_ACCOUNT")
credentials = compute_engine.Credentials()
project_id = os.environ.get("PROJECT_ID")

def get_bucket(bucket_name):
    client = storage.Client(credentials=credentials, project=project_id)
    bucket = client.get_bucket(bucket_name)
    return bucket

def generate_presigned_url_for_profile(blob_name, expiration=3600):
    storage_client = storage.Client()
    bucket = storage_client.bucket(bucket_name)
    blob = bucket.blob(f"userProfile/{blob_name}")
    url = blob.generate_signed_url(version="v4", expiration=datetime.timedelta(seconds=expiration), method='GET', service_account_email=service_account)
    return url


I've tried using compute.engine.Credentials() and it didn't work

Turns out the answer is just at the back of my eye, I've adde this code:
GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    "/SECRETS/SERVICE_ACCOUNT"
)

and modifying this code:
    client = storage.Client(credentials=GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS)

then make a secret volume in the cloud run, mount it and re-deploy, now it works like I wanted

This issue and a(n older solution) is documented by Google generate_signed_url: "If you are on Google Compute Engine, you can't generate a signed URL using GCE service account. If you'd like to be able to generate a signed URL from GCE, you can use a standard service account from a JSON file rather than a GCE service account.". However, you can now also do this. See: https://stackoverflow.com/a/64245028/609290
